# Trying to submit data using Ajax without page load with on change event of select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to submit the selected value using ajax to avoid a page load. even with the "return false;" there is still a page load. **Data is posted successfully, but the page still refreshes.**

```
<div style='display:none;' id='RCTruckTH' name='RCTruckTH'>
<br><label>Height in meters *</label>
    <select class="form-control" style="max-width:300px!important;" id='RCTruckHV' name='RCTruckHV'>
         <option <?php if(isset($_SESSION['RCTruckHV']) && $_SESSION['RCTruckHV'] == "1.8m") echo "selected";?>>1.8m</option>
         <option <?php if(isset($_SESSION['RCTruckHV']) && $_SESSION['RCTruckHV'] == "1.9m") echo "selected";?>>1.9m</option>
         <option <?php if(isset($_SESSION['RCTruckHV']) && $_SESSION['RCTruckHV'] == "2.0m") echo "selected";?>>2.0m</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#RCTruckHV').on('change', function() {
            var rcheival = $selected_value=$('#RCTruckHV option:selected').text();
            localStorage.setItem('rcheival', rcheival);
            //console.log(rcheival);

                $.ajax({
                   url: 'RDSetSession.php',
                   type: 'get',
                   data: {
                             'rcheival': rcheival
                         },
                         success: function() {
                         location.reload();
                     }
               });
           return false;
     });
});
```

FIX: Removing both:
location.reload(); and
return false;
fixed the issue as mentioned by @JayBlanchard

Comment: Uh, `location.reload()`? Remove that line and there is no need for `return false;`

Comment: What else `location.reload()` supposed to do?

Comment: Thanks, @JayBlanchard removing both return false and location. reload fixed my problem. Thanks so much for your quick response.

Comment: There is nothing to trigger a reload once that code is gone. There has to be code somewhere else in the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `location.reload();`, this causes the page to reload when the AJAX succeeds. Additionally there is no need for `return false;`